# I set up a git staging server, the files aren't appearing after I push

Tags: git

I've set up a few of these and got them working, but on my one server I can't seem to get the files to show up on the staging server.  I can push to live, and they show up no problem.

Steps taken on server:

```
mkdir staging
cd staging
mkdir staging.git
cd staging.git
git init --bare
cd hooks
touch post-receive
nano post-receive
chmod +x post-receive
```

I posted the following in the post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/my-site.com/public_html/staging git checkout -f master
```

From my local machine I did:

```
git remote add staging myuser@my-site.com:/var/www/my-site.com/staging/staging.git
git add .
git commit -m "Pushing to staging"
git push staging master
```

The git pushes fine, no errors, but the files are nowhere to be found.  This is the exact same setup I've used successfully on other servers, and the exact same setup I used for pushing to live, which works.

I messed up my original setup with this, deleted the entire staging directory from the server, removed the remote and re-started the whole process.  I assume there is something I missed along the way?

My second part to this question is, does my .git folder have to be in the staging folder, or does the GIT_WORK_TREE path just have to point to the staging folder, and the remote needs to point to the .git folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only step I don't see in your setup is a `chmod +x post-receive`, to make sure it is executable.

I would use the more reliable:

```
 git --git-dir=/var/www/my-site.com/staging/staging.git --work-tree=/var/www/my-site.com/staging checkout -f master
```

> does my `.git` folder have to be in the staging folder,

Your bare repo can be anywhere you want, provided it is visible/addressed by the http file server.
That differs from the working tree, which references the folder where you checkout code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated my question because I forgot to mention that I did run this to make sure the file is executable.

Comment: @drewkroft ok. Can you add an echo in that script, just to be sure it runs when you push?

Comment: So, I added - echo Pushed Okay! - to the post-receive script.  Edited the index.html file, pushed again.  The "Pushed Okay!" message showed up, then I refreshed the staging directory in the browser and the page showed up fine... ?  Glad it works, but not sure why that change made the difference, or if maybe it was an issue with the browser cache or something?

Comment: @drewkroft no caching should be involved. Double-check by removing the echo and checking it still work.

Comment: Removed the echo, made a change and pushed again... The change showed up fine.  I'm more confused now than I was when it wasn't working.

Comment: @drewkroft I have added a more reliable git command, but other than that, the file must not have been properly executable before your test. Or the master branch was somehow empty.

Comment: I used your recommended more reliable code for the post-receive document.  It's working great, thanks!